# how do I tell my boss I'd like to work from home on a regular basis?

Tags: communication, work-environment, company-culture

I am unsure how to ask that because I am the most junior employee, and as far as I know no one else in the company works from home. If they accepted I would feel like I am getting special treatment, and most of all I don't want to look like a slacker. we are pretty flexible with our schedule (some work 8 to 4, some 10 to 6) but no one ever works an entire day from home, apart from when they are taking an actual day off. the main reason I want to work from home is that the office is far from where I live (1h20 commute), so I would gain almost three hours of free time every day.

I am well aware that sometimes I *need* to physically be there, for example when we have meetings. but if I had 2 or 3 days a week where I could develop from home, it would be huge quality of life improvement for me.

in short, how do I approach my boss about this?

Comment: Think again, if it will really make your life better. Once I let a person work from home regularly, and after the first such day he said, he will never do it again, because his kids are too loud and he cannot focus. He used a lot of relationship credit with me for nothing. If you are certain, go on. Also be prepared to answer why you want to work from home. No commute time is a good answer so that you can pick up the kids or study for exams. More time to play Battlefield or CoD is not.

Comment: @Mark, I'm curious why someone asking you this question would "use a lot of relationship credit"? You mean you liked them less because they asked you a perfectly legitimate question in an attempt to improve their work situation? That sentence really stuck out to me as something that I hope my manager would _never_ say about me if I were to ask such a question.

Answer (score 7):

Just be straight:

"Hi Boss, I'd really like to work from home on a regular basis.  What can I do to make that happen?"

If it's not possible, the boss will let you know right away.  If it is then you'll find out how.   Nothing else matters.

Comment: +1 for not wasting anyones time and being concise.

Answer (score 6):

You need to explain to your boss the benefit *to him* of having you work from home. At the moment, your post is all about the benefits for you.

Note that unless there are non-trivial benefits to the business of you working from home, you may well just have to accept that you're not going to be working from home on a regular basis. Without wanting to be to blunt about it, you knew the deal when you joined the company.